# MySQL Insert, how to get incremental id from insert

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO db.a (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 
VALUES (2,2,"a",'b','c','d',1,'e',0)
```

The first insert will insert a new row with a incremental_id.  I need to take that incremental_id and make an entry into `db.b` using that incremental_id, for example, if it was `6005` I would make the following insert.

```
INSERT INTO db.b 
(a_id, s_id, use_i)
VALUES (6005,7,0)
```

How can I automatically grab the id of the first insert so my second insert can be built dynamically after the first query?

Comment: Use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

Comment: to add to @Barmar 's comment you might need to do `SET @a_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();` after insert into `a` table and use `SET @s_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();` after inserting into a `s` table   and use `INSERT INTO db.b 
(a_id, s_id, use_i)
VALUES (@a_id,@s_id,0)`  .. As it is not very clear if you have or don't have a `s` table as i saw `s_id` i assumed you also have a `s` table

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which will return exactly what you need.